# Pursuing Maths after Majoring in Engineering

Tags: education

I will be graduating this summer with an undergraduate degree in Mechanical Engineering. I want to pursue my interest in the field of mathematics. If anyone can provide guidance on how to go about it?

Also is it possible if I want to get a Bachelors in Mathematics (I know most schools won't accept me since I already hold a degree)? If yes, any guidance? I am up for any good schools anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think what you said about most schools not accepting you is generally true. I do however think that pure mathematics is a different beast than engineering, so at the very least, some reading should be done between this degree and the next.

Comment: Can you suggest me some places which I can apply to considering my case?

Comment: Can you list any examples of universities that you cannot apply to?

Comment: http://www.admission.ucla.edu/prospect/applying.htm

It says it won't accept students for second Bachelors degree. Is there any way to pursue an undergraduate degree in Mathematics?

Comment: I am also facing a similar situation. Tried browsing in google for an answer. Maybe it will be of some help to you. [Here](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-pursue-a-MS-in-mathematics-after-completing-B-Tech-in-chemical-engineering) is a link to a Quora page discussing a similar topic.